# How to use Condition properly to wait and notifyAll without losing the notification?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a group of tasks and they are separated into two parts `enque` and `deque` to ensure the **qualified** (more than one) run first and **then** other qualified in order (something like priority queue).

Within the `enque`, tasks will be checked and only the `qualified` tasks will be executed while the other `unqualified` blocked.

Within the `deque`, tasks finished will be removed from the `queue` and then `notifyAll` the blocked (actually all other threads to select the **qualified**).

Here is a simplified demo for what I am trying to achieve:

```
class MyTaskQueue {
    private static final Object THE_QUEUE_LOCK = new Object();
    public static Map<String, ReentrantLock> taskGroupLock = new HashMap<>();
    public static Map<String, Condition> taskGroupCondition = new HashMap<>();

    public static void enque(String name, String taskId) {
        synchronized (THE_QUEUE_LOCK) {
            taskGroupLock.putIfAbsent(name, new ReentrantLock());
            taskGroupCondition.putIfAbsent(name, taskGroupLock.get(name).newCondition());
        }
        synchronized (taskGroupLock.get(name)) {
            while (true) {
                if (isValid(taskId)) {
                    break; // Go!!;
                } else {
                    try {
                        taskGroupCondition.get(name).wait(); // blocked if it's not allowed;
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                        ignored.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void deque(String name, String taskId) {
        if (taskGroup.containsKey(name) && taskGroup.get(name).contains(taskId)) {
            synchronized (THE_QUEUE_LOCK) {
                taskGroup.get(name).remove(taskId);
                if (taskGroup.get(name).isEmpty()) {
                    taskGroup.remove(name);
                }
                synchronized (taskGroupLock.get(name)) {
                    taskGroupCondition.get(name).notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

For now, only the first task will be executed though I checked all others (at least most of them) are properly blocked.

But when I checked the `taskGroupCondition.get(name)`, the `firstWaiter` and `lastWaiter` are both `null`.

Something I missed here?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Qualified tasks run in parallel or in serial order?

Comment: @thanopi57 Thanks for the help, yes they're **parallelised**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are asking the following:

1. Threads running in parallel request from your `MyTaskQueue` permission to start running (via the `enque` method).
2. `enque` method of `MyTaskQueue` blocks until the task requesting to run gets qualified.
3. Each qualified Thread declares to `MyTaskQueue` that it has ended running, by calling the `deque` method.
4. `deque` method notifies all other tasks, so as to check which of them are qualified, which in turn start running.

Then I can see the following solution:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class MyTaskQueue {

    private final Map<String, Set<String>> runningTasks;
    private String qualifiedTaskId;

    public MyTaskQueue(String initialQualifiedTaskId) {
        runningTasks = new HashMap<>();
        qualifiedTaskId = initialQualifiedTaskId;
    }

    private synchronized boolean isValid(String taskId) {
        return qualifiedTaskId != null && taskId != null && taskId.equals(qualifiedTaskId); //Do your qualification tests here...
    }

    public synchronized void setQualifiedTaskId(String qualifiedTaskId) {
        this.qualifiedTaskId = qualifiedTaskId;
        notifyAll(); //Now that the qualification test changed, is time to notify every blocked task.
        //This way, all new qualified tasks will also be started. This "notifyAll()" operation is optional.
    }

    public synchronized void enque(String task, String taskId) {
        while (!isValid(taskId)) { //Reentrant lock.
            System.out.println("Blocking unqualified task {\"" + task + "\", \"" + taskId + "\"}...");
            try { wait(); } catch (InterruptedException ie) { /*Handle the exception...*/ }
        }
        runningTasks.putIfAbsent(task, new HashSet<>());
        runningTasks.get(task).add(taskId);
        System.out.println("Starting qualified task {\"" + task + "\", \"" + taskId + "\"}...");
    }

    //Optional method. Might be needed for example if a Thread
    //wants to check if another task is currently running...
    public synchronized boolean isRunning(String task, String taskId) {
        return runningTasks.containsKey(task) && runningTasks.get(task).contains(taskId);
    }

    public synchronized void deque(String task, String taskId) {
        if (isRunning(task, taskId)) { //Reentrant lock.

            //Cleanup:
            runningTasks.get(task).remove(taskId);
            if (runningTasks.get(task).isEmpty())
                runningTasks.remove(task);

            //Notify all blocked tasks:
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        MyTaskQueue q = new MyTaskQueue("qualified");
        Random rand = new Random();
        new MyThread(q, "Task1", "qualified222", 2500 + rand.nextInt(500)).start();
        new MyThread(q, "Task2", "qualified222", 2500 + rand.nextInt(500)).start();
        new MyThread(q, "Task3", "qualified", 2500 + rand.nextInt(500)).start();
        new MyThread(q, "Task4", "qualified", 2500 + rand.nextInt(500)).start();
        new MyThread(q, "Task5", "foreverBlocked", 2500 + rand.nextInt(500)).start();
        try { Thread.sleep(3000); } catch (InterruptedException ie) { /*Handle the exception...*/ }
        synchronized (q) {
            System.out.println("Qualifying tasks of id \"qualified222\"...");
            q.setQualifiedTaskId("qualified222"); //Reentrant lock.
        }
        //Execution of main method never ends, because of the forever blocked task "Task5".
        //The "Task5" still runs while waiting for permission... See MyThread for details...
    }
}
```

And follows `MyThread`:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private final String task, taskId;
    private final int actionTime; //Dummy uptime to simulate.
    private final MyTaskQueue q;

    public MyThread(MyTaskQueue q, String task, String taskId, int actionTime) {
        this.q = q;
        this.task = task;
        this.taskId = taskId;
        this.actionTime = actionTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        q.enque(task, taskId); //Wait for permission to run...
        System.out.println("Task {\"" + task + "\", \"" + taskId + "\"} is currently running...");

        //Now lets actually execute the task of the Thread:
        try { Thread.sleep(actionTime); } catch (InterruptedException ie) { /*Handle the exception.*/ }

        q.deque(task, taskId); //Declare Thread ended.
    }
}
```

`MyThread` is the class which performs the actual operations needed.

For simplicity, I supposed that a task is qualified if its id is equal to a variable (namely `qualifiedTaskId`).

There is also a `main` method to test the code.

Follows sample output (and I numbered the lines):

1. Blocking unqualified task {"Task1", "qualified222"}…
2. Blocking unqualified task {"Task5", "blocked"}…
3. Starting qualified task {"Task4", "qualified"}…
4. Task {"Task4", "qualified"} is currently running...
5. Starting qualified task {"Task3", "qualified"}…
6. Task {"Task3", "qualified"} is currently running...
7. Blocking unqualified task {"Task2", "qualified222"}…
8. Blocking unqualified task {"Task2", "qualified222"}…
9. Blocking unqualified task {"Task5", "blocked"}…
10. Blocking unqualified task {"Task1", "qualified222"}…
11. Blocking unqualified task {"Task1", "qualified222"}…
12. Blocking unqualified task {"Task5", "blocked"}…
13. Blocking unqualified task {"Task2", "qualified222"}…
14. Qualifying tasks of id "qualified222"...
15. Starting qualified task {"Task2", "qualified222"}…
16. Task {"Task2", "qualified222"} is currently running...
17. Blocking unqualified task {"Task5", "blocked"}…
18. Starting qualified task {"Task1", "qualified222"}…
19. Task {"Task1", "qualified222"} is currently running...
20. Blocking unqualified task {"Task5", "blocked"}…
21. Blocking unqualified task {"Task5", "blocked"}…

As you can see, lines 1 to 7 are the initial message for each thread.
Then, lines 8 to 10 are called because a qualified task ended (so they are re-blocked).
Then, lines 11 to 13 are called because another qualified task ended (so they are re-blocked).
Then, in lines 14 to 19 the qualification test changes and the new qualified tasks start running. There is still another task (`Task5`) which is not qualified yet.
Finally, lines 20 to 21 are called because of the qualified tasks with task id equal to `"qualified222"` end.

Comment: Elegant solution. Thank you so much.